# Echo option value with selected

Tags: php

Im tryin to fix when i press my search button. That the selected search from my option field remains selected. But at the moment it automaticly picks the first field of the options in my form.

First one is hardcoded and it works.

```
<option value="HS" <?= ($nickval == 'HS' ? 'selected="selected' : '')?>>Homer Simpsons</option>
```

But then i wanted to echo out option value from database so its not hardcoded.

```
<?php
while(db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) {
 echo "<option value='$pin'>$fullname</option>";
}
?>
```

And now when i want to add if its selected i tried to solve it like this.

```
echo "<option value='$pin'($nickval == '$pin' ? 'selected='selected'' : '')>$fullname </option>";
```

This is how i get my pin

```
 $pin = db2_result($queryexe, 'P510PIN');
```

This is how i get my $nickval

```
 $nickval = $_GET["int"];
```

Any suggestions what im doin wrong? Sorry if im unclear but i've tried my best

Comment: It's a `"` `'` mix

Comment: Surely PHP is telling you about the syntax errors on that line of code...

Comment: I tried with '' instead of "  but it doesnt work.

Comment: how can i get to see the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from quoting errors indicated in the syntax highlighting...

You're trying to execute PHP code inside of a string:

```
echo "<option value='$pin'($nickval == '$pin' ? 'selected='selected'' : '')>$fullname </option>";
```

Variable interpolation is one thing, but code inside of a string isn't going to automatically execute.  It's just a string being echoed to the page.  (Check the page source and see what's actually being emitted to the browser.)

Separate the strings from the code which builds the strings:

```
echo "<option value='$pin' " . ($nickval == $pin ? "selected='selected'" : "") . ">$fullname </option>";
```

Comment: I dont get any "selected", This is what i get now <option value="HM">Homer Simpson              </option>

Comment: @Mato: When you debug this, what are the runtime values of `$nickval` and `$pin` (including whitespace)?

Comment: Sorry but i have much to do, i will answer as fast as i can

Comment: I printed out both nickval and pin, but nickval is totaly wrong.

Comment: @Mato: Well, if the values are different then that would explain why comparing them returns false.

Comment: somehow my $pin is always "EK" and Ek is the last one echo'd

Comment: I have tried one more thing,. becuse my $pin is always "EK", i fixed so my nickval is ek to, but still it doesnt get "selected"

Comment: @Mato: `"EK"` and `"ek"` are different values, so the comparison would still be `false`.  This is going well outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: i mean both are exactly the same, i was just wrote it bad here. Both are EK = EK

Comment: @Mato: You're going to have to do some debugging.  Determine the *exact* values (including any whitespace) and examine the actual resulting HTML (not just the behavior of the form element).

Comment: I think i found a solution, Cuz i do echo in while loop . my pin will always be last pin, So i just got to move nickval to pin everytime, so they are the same. i Give u one A for the effort

Comment: How can  i move value from $nickval to $pin?

Comment: @Mato: `$pin = $nickval` ?

Comment: yeah i did it.. damn still your thing doesnt work for me

 echo "<option value='$pin' " . ($nickval == $pin ? "selected='selected'" : "") . ">$fullname </option>";

Comment: Can it be cuz my first EK is like "EK   " and other is "EK"

Comment: @Mato: Whitespace differences are differences, yes.

Comment: Ok sorry to bother you, I've tried one new thing, I did like $nickval = "EK" and $pin = "EK" but still this  . ($nickval == $pin ? "selected='selected'" : "") doesnt work

Comment: Finally solved it. i changed place on my get, i put it before while loop, sorry to bother you, thank you again.